# The Value of textbox is still appear After page reload in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, textbox

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
            {
                txtUserName.Text = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
                
                txtPass.Attributes.Add("value", Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["Password"].Value));
               
                CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            }
        }

    }

    protected void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {  }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = "Login In Failed";
            }

            ClearField();
        }
    }

    protected void ClearField()
    {
        txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtPass.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

When my **else** condition execute. it not empty my **txtPass** Textbox instead if i write wrong password it display correct password in textbox.

i think something wrong with Cookie but idk how to solve it.

Comment: Why you are populating password field like?
 txtPass.Attributes.Add("value", Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["Password"].Value));

Comment: becoz in textbox i use the attribute TextMode=Password. first i use txtPass.Text = Request.Cookies["Password"].Value; and its not showing anything in txtPass.

Comment: It is by design, for security reasons, so that the password is not in the HTML in plain text.

Comment: so what is reason txtPass is getting the value?  due to Attribute.Add ?

Comment: What if you remove that code? What is the end output you want?

Comment: i just want if user enter wrong Name or Password it shows LblMsg = "Login Failed" and clear the txtUSerName and txtPass textbox. but it just clear txtUSername name not txtPass.      if i remove Attribute.Add, so user have to enter his Name and Password when ever he want to signIn.

Comment: I would suggest instead of showing the login page redirect the user to main page if he already have a active session.

Comment: txtPass.Attribute.Clear(); solution the problem. U r right Attribute messing up. Thanks!